# parallel threads need to reach a point, wait on another thread, and then resume - best approach?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

**Here's the (simplified) scenario:**

- I have threads A, B, C running in parallel.
- Once all 3 threads have reached Step 7 of their execution, they must wait. (Each thread will reach Step 7 at a different time, which can't be known in advance).
- Thread D then kicks off and runs to completion.
- Only after D completes can A, B, and C resume and run to completion.

**What would be a good tool or design to approach this with?**

The concurrency and semaphore examples I've looked at so far seem to only deal with 2 threads, or assume that the parallel threads are doing similar things but just sharing a var or message-passing. I haven't yet found anything that works with the scenario above. I'm continuing to look into it and will update with any findings.

A CountDownLatch might work if it didn't need to have the other threads exit. Or if it could work in reverse - make `n` threads wait until thread D exits.

I'm fairly new to concurrency (college classes do not give it anywhere near the time it needs), so bear with me. Dropping this link here in case anyone with a similar question stumbles on this thread: [HowToDoInJava - Concurrency](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/)

Comment: To have threads `A`, `B`, and `C` wait at step 7, I'd probably go with a [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). Then, you can run thread `D` in the `Runnable` that you pass to the `CyclicBarrier`'s constructor, and wait for it to complete before allowing threads `A`, `B`, and `C` to continue.

Comment: @JacobG. if you add it as an answer I think that would be the most updated one since it satisfies all the requirements from the question.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html)

```
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;

class Scratch {
    public static class ThreadABCWorker implements Runnable {
        String threadName;
        Phaser phaser;

        public ThreadABCWorker(String threadName, Phaser phaser) {
            this.threadName =  threadName;
            this.phaser = phaser;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " has started");
            // do steps 1-7 as part of phase 0
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            // All the work for phase 1 is done in Thread D, so just arrive again and wait for D to do its thing
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            System.out.println("Continue Thread" + threadName);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var phaser = new Phaser(4);
        var threadA = new Thread(new ThreadABCWorker("A", phaser));
        var threadB = new Thread(new ThreadABCWorker("B", phaser));
        var threadC = new Thread(new ThreadABCWorker("C", phaser));
        var threadD = new Thread(() -> {
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // D shouldn't start doing its thing until phase 1
            System.out.println("Thread D has started");

            try {
                System.out.println("sleep 100");
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println("Thread D has finished");
                phaser.arriveAndDeregister(); // All done, let ths other threads continue
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        threadA.start();
        threadB.start();
        threadC.start();
        threadD.start();
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Thread A has started
Thread C has started
Thread B has started
Thread D has started
sleep 100
Thread D has finished
Continue ThreadB
Continue ThreadA
Continue ThreadC
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  
I tried implementing it, and while it does keep A,B,C from continuing until D is finished, it doesn't keep D from starting until A,B,C reach the wait point/Step 7.  
What happens: D starts at the same time as the rest (aside from the sleep, but trying to time an appropriate sleep isn't a solution to having D wait for A,B,C to reach a certain point).  
What needs to happen: D doesn't start until A,B,C reach the wait point.  
I think I need 2 locks for this...

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the requirement at first.  I've edited the code so that D waits to start working until A, B, and C get to "step 7".   Basically, A, B, and C do work in phase 0, D does its work in phase 1, and then A, B, and C continue doing their work in phase 2.  Having only one synchronization object is easier to reason about IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with using the `CountDownLatch` itself. It doesn't necessarily have to countdown only when threads complete.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

/**
 * Sample class that utilizes very simple thread creation/execution.
 * <p>
 * DISCLAIMER: This class isn't meant to show all cross-cutting concerns. It just focuses on the task presented.
 * Naming conventions, access modifiers, etc. may not be optimal.
 */
public class ATech {

    private static long startThreadTime;
    private static CountDownLatch primaryCountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);
    private static CountDownLatch secondaryCountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Thread> threads = Arrays.asList(
                new Thread(new ThreadType1("A", 1, 5)),
                new Thread(new ThreadType1("B", 5, 1)),
                new Thread(new ThreadType1("C", 10, 10)),
                new Thread(new ThreadType2("D", 5))
        );

        startThreadTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Starting threads at (about) time 0");

        threads.forEach(Thread::start);

        try {
            for (Thread thread : threads) {
                thread.join();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        System.out.println("All threads completed at time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startThreadTime));
    }

    static class ThreadType1 implements Runnable {

        public ThreadType1(String name, int executionTimePreWaitInSeconds, int executionTimePostWaitInSeconds) {
            this.execTimePreWait = executionTimePreWaitInSeconds;
            this.execTimePostWait = executionTimePostWaitInSeconds;
            this.name = name;
        }

        int execTimePreWait;
        int execTimePostWait;
        String name;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Execution thread " + name + ". Waiting for " + execTimePreWait + " seconds");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(execTimePreWait * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            // Done doing whatever we were doing, now we let the other thread now we're done (for now)
            System.out.println("Thread " + name + " completed at time " + (System
                    .currentTimeMillis() - startThreadTime) + ". Waiting for latch");

            primaryCountDownLatch.countDown();

            try {
                secondaryCountDownLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);

            }

            System.out.println(
                    "Thread " + name + " awoken again at time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startThreadTime));
            System.out.println("Thread " + name + " will sleep for " + execTimePostWait + " seconds");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(execTimePostWait * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            System.out.println(
                    "Thread " + name + " completed fully at time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startThreadTime));
        }
    }

    static class ThreadType2 implements Runnable {

        String name;
        int execTime;

        public ThreadType2(String name, int executionTimeInSeconds) {
            this.name = name;
            this.execTime = executionTimeInSeconds;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread " + name + " waiting for other threads to complete");
            try {
                primaryCountDownLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            System.out.println("Thread " + name + " woke up at time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startThreadTime));
            System.out.println("Thread " + name + " will work for " + execTime + " seconds");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(execTime * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            System.out.println("Thread " + name + " completed at time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startThreadTime));
            secondaryCountDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Starting threads at (about) time 0
Execution thread A. Waiting for 1 seconds
Execution thread C. Waiting for 10 seconds
Execution thread B. Waiting for 5 seconds
Thread D waiting for other threads to complete
Thread A completed at time 1033. Waiting for latch
Thread B completed at time 5034. Waiting for latch
Thread C completed at time 10034. Waiting for latch
Thread D woke up at time 10034
Thread D will work for 5 seconds
Thread D completed at time 15034
Thread A awoken again at time 15034
Thread C awoken again at time 15034
Thread A will sleep for 5 seconds
Thread B awoken again at time 15034
Thread B will sleep for 1 seconds
Thread C will sleep for 10 seconds
Thread B completed fully at time 16035
Thread A completed fully at time 20034
Thread C completed fully at time 25034
All threads completed at time 25034

Process finished with exit code 0
```